# Some api calls fail on Android 9

Tags: java, android

I have an app that works perfectly on devices lower than Android 9. I just implemented `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on my Manifest to support Android 9 and above. The problem is, on my samsung note 8 the app works fine but on a friend's samsung note 8; some api calls always fail even with good network connection. What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For all your suggestions. To solve my problem i did a toast to display the endpoint being called by device and notice %20 been added to my parameter. %20 means a space is present and this came during the user registration on the app which was no problem at that point. So to solve this i added a trim() on getting the text from my edittext views to get the exact details without spaces and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by Creating `network_security_config.xml` in res -> xml folder

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true"> /* your base url Eg: http://mide.awsnode.com/ */</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true"> /*--- another url (if have) */ </domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

In the Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/new_logo_ag"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" // define the xml
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/new_logo_ag"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="n">
```

May be this could help you

Comment: Thanks @Dutchman but i already have this implemented. Now the device can communicate with my registration api but can't do same with the other apis i have. Seems really strange.I can't figure out the cause.